# Holding single player mini-campaigns before starting the main campaign with the full party?

Tags: gm-techniques

Is there any precedent for the DM to have one-on-one mini-campaigns with some or all of the player, before the main campaign with everyone as a single party begins? I thought of a fun twist where during those prequel campaigns some of the players meet each other as NPCs in the other's story, but I don't tell them that they're actually interacting with a future party member. Perhaps they're wearing disguises during this interaction so they don't immediately recognize each other when they join up as a party to start the main story.

Anyways, just wondering if this has been done before, if there's any guidance on it, or anything or the sort.

Comment: Hi, @xojfqa.  First things first:  Welcome to the site, and if you haven't already take a look at the [tour], please go ahead and browse through it.

Comment: Second, I really hate to be the one to start this process, but, while this is a mostly good question that I am sure this stack can give good advice on, I think we really need to know what game you're planning this with.  (I know this because I've done it or been part of it in several different games, and my advice is substantially different for those different games.)  This is why you're going to get some close votes on the question-- not because it's a bad question, but to help improve it.

Answer (score 8):

There’s certainly precedent in other games (I’m assuming from some of your language that you’re playing D&D or something similar). The ones I’m most familiar with are *Vampire: The Masquerade* and many of the other World of Darkness games, which have long suggested running a “Prelude” for each character. This tells the story of how each character was Embraced (became a vampire) or otherwise became part of the supernatural world. The main rulebooks for most of the World of Darkness games include advice on this in the chapter for Storytellers (the game system’s term for the GM). Preludes are usually short - either one session or at most one for each player’s character, with the other players encouraged to play guest roles in each other’s stories.

I think this is a good rule of thumb for any game, though, even when running these types of sessions solo for just the player: keep it short, and jump through time to the most important bits.

In my experience these constraints serve two purposes: it concentrates the prelude/prequel campaign on what will be immediately useful for the player(s) going into the game proper, and leaves plenty of room to flesh out the character through play in the main campaign.

In your scenario, if you’re running these one-on-one but want the other PCs to show up as NPCs - presumably played by you - make sure you give those players input into what their characters are doing. This doesn’t have to be direct; depending on the system and the kind of character questions you ask as part of your setup, and the expectations around player agency established during session zero for the game, you should have plenty to work with. Just make sure the players are happy with whatever you’re doing with their characters.

My other bit of advice is to have an end point in mind, and *tell the player what that is*, so you’re on the same page about bringing everyone to the same starting point. You don’t have to be too specific, and it could even be a motivation you want them to end up with, rather than a place they need to be.

There are other D&D fantasy style specific versions, but these are often focussed on the party’s first adventure together, for example the “Character Funnel” of *Dungeon Crawl Classics*, which throws zero-level characters into a first-level adventure and sees if they survive.